# Is something weird happening to wrapdb.mesonbuild.com?

Tags: ssl-certificate, meson-build

I am using [meson build system](https://mesonbuild.com/), but this morning I have a problem with 
**wrapdb.mesonbuild.com**.

With my computer and another one (for checking), when using a web browser like Chromium or Firefox, I get messages like:

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from wrapdb.mesonbuild.com 
(for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
```

(I have checked my computer time etc... with **ntpdate**... so I priori this is not the origin of the problem)

Also any attempt to use:

```
meson wrap list
```

fails, with output like:

```
SSL connection failed. Falling back to unencrypted connections.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1422, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1076)
```

Can you reproduce? I cannot find the source of the problem.

---

**update**: it seems that wrapdb.mesonbuild.com has already been down in the past:

https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/3497

maybe this is my current problem.

---

**update 2**: I did not have the reflex but with

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=wrapdb.mesonbuild.com

one can see that the site's certificate expired yesterday...

Also thanks to @TomEsposito for pointing out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears their SSL Certificate expired yesterday, but they are still using HTTPS. Until they update their certificate, or move to an HTTP connection, your browser will continue to warn you of this. All modern browsers now warn users when a site is using HTTPS but there is no certificate

Comment: thanks for confirming this, I now know that the origin of the problem is not my computer.

Comment: Correct, it's an issue on their end and not yours. You can raise an issue in GitHub for them to renew their Let's Encrypt Certificate. Other than that, you will just have to wait for them.

Comment: I understand. However after this I am currently modifying my meson.build files to do not depend on wrapdb anymore.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge on the meson.build files, so I can't be much help there. However, looking at the file output you added, it looks like they also fail because of the bad SSL Cert.